# Firebase Hosting : Deploy is not working - it stops & not gives any response

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am Trying to Deploy my one-page website in Firebase Hosting, I was able to successfully initiate and serve the Website on my local system.

After using `firebase deploy` there is no response from the server. I kept it for more than 12 hours, but it is stuck there only and nothing updated or deployed.

Please Check the log here :

```
 [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\babu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase deploy
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] CLI Version:   3.18.6
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] Platform:      win32
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] Node Version:  v9.11.1
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] Time:          Wed Aug 15 2018 09:41:14 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.975Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [debug] 
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.985Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.985Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:14.994Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/functions-project-97a23  

     Wed Aug 15 2018 09:41:14 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:16.011Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:16.011Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/functions-project-97a23/tokens  

     Wed Aug 15 2018 09:41:16 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-08-15T05:41:16.873Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
```

## I have completed similar task 3 months back, but same procedure is not working now.

---

Here is My Command line:

```
 E:\Download\Compressed\Extra\GGM>firebase deploy --only hosting
    ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y

    E:\Download\Compressed\Extra\GGM>firebase serve

    === Serving from 'E:\Download\Compressed\Extra\GGM'...

    i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
    i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: GGMFinal
    +  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000

    Warning: You're using Node.js v9.11.1 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
    i  functions: No HTTPS functions found. Use firebase functions:shell if you would like to emulate other types of functions.
    Shutting down...
    Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

    E:\Download\Compressed\Extra\GGM>firebase functions:shell
    i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
    Warning: You're using Node.js v9.11.1 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
    i  functions: No functions to emulate.
    No functions emulated.

    E:\Download\Compressed\Extra\GGM>firebase deploy
    ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y

    E:\Download\Compressed\Extra\GGM>
```

Comment: If you have a problem with the Firebase CLI simply not working the way you expect, contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Looks like your timezone is set to "Arabian Standard Time". Are you from the UAE? According to [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/), there's an issue with ISPs in the UAE and India. Incident began at 2018-08-13 00:00 (US-Pacific), still ongoing at 15/08/2018.

Comment: Yes, I am now located in UAE. Can you Please How Can I fix this.